# My com.mongoDB jar file don't have a mongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea

[image]

When I connect to mongoDB with java, my mongodb jar doesn't have a mongoClient, I don't know why ? pls help me fixes

Answer (score 0):

You need **[Mongo Java Driver](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.2.2)** (JAR from Sonatype)

And here's Mongo Java Driver [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/)